# How to get %s recognized in a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, forfiles

I have a 3-command .bat file that runs fine as 3 separate commands (entered 1 at a time into command line) but does not work when I put them as 3 lines in a bat file.

Here's the file:

```
mogrify -format pgm ephemeral:*.png
pause
CALL forfiles /M *.pgm /C "cmd /c for %s in (@fname) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i %s.pgm -o %s.ppm
pause
mogrify -format png ephemeral:*.ppm
```

The first command runs fine, but the command line gives me this error for the second command:

```
s.pgm was unexpected at this time
```

The reason I have that for loop with fname and %s is because the debayer.exe program doesn't understand @fname.pgm as a filename, but it does realize that's means bring in a string, so it does that, and then forfiles recognizes @fname and replaces it with the current file name.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

I have tried:

1. Putting `%%` instead of `%`
2. Putting a `^` infront of each `%`
3. Adding the `CALL` that is in the above code
4. Adding semicolons to the end of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the `CALL` it's useless here and it will start the parse a second time so it will remove percent signs.

And double the percent signs, as they will be halfed one time.

```
forfiles /M *.pgm /C "cmd /c for %%s in (@fname) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i %%s.pgm -o %%s.ppm
```

Answer (score 1):

You also don't need forfiles.  A straight forward for loop will work.

```
mogrify -format pgm ephemeral:*.png
pause
for %%s in (*.pgm) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i "%%s" -o "%%~ns.ppm"
pause
mogrify -format png ephemeral:*.ppm
```

Comment: Would you like to describe how it fails?